# docker-compose traefik issue with PathRegexp

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a docker-compose file with 4 containers traefik, UI, API and DB.

I want to use traefik to redirect both containers UI and API to port 80 but on a different url path.
UI is redirected directly to localhost:80 and API I want to redirect to localhost/api, but the problem is that localhost/api is already taken in the UI container by valid html code. So I need to exclude it from the API routing or provide a valid PathRegexp which I am failing to create.

**Here is the docker-compose where Iam trying PathRegexp:**

Idea is to redirect only api endpointslike */api/endpoint1* or */api/endpoint2* but not redirect */api* itself as that one I need to be redirected to UI container.

```
version: "3"

services:

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./api/dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathRegexp(`^/api/.*`)"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./ui/dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - api
      - db
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - ./ui/html/:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.ui.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
    ports:
      - 81:81
      - 443:443

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $ROOT_PASS_MYSQL
        MYSQL_DATABASE: $PRACTICE_DB
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

With this configuration I am getting an error:

*error while parsing rule Host(`localhost`) && PathRegexp(`^/api/.*`): unsupported function: PathRegexp*

Answer (score 0):

`PathRegexp` does not exist (anymore). You can use `Path` or `PathPrefix` (see: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule)

You can use

```yaml
traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/api/`)
```

This will send `/api` to the UI container (but `/api/` goes to the other container).

If you need `/api/`(trailing slash) to go to the UI container, you can use a regex like so:

```yaml
traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`localhost`) && Path(`/api/{regex:.+}`)
```

Note that `regex` here is just the name of the match group, it can be changed to anything else. `.+` makes sure that it only matches if there is at least one character after `/api/`.

In general, the longest rules have the highest priority.

Comment: thx, and how can i resolve my issue where i need the path /api/ to be redirected to UI container while everything after path /api/ (for example /api/test or /api/another-test) needs to be redirected to API container?